# ¿Cómo extraigo las palabras de un vector que contienen las letras de un string?

Tags: c++, dev-c++, c++20

Tengo un `vector<string>` que contiene una serie de palabras dentro y un string con unas pocas letras. Quiero extraer todas las palabras de ese vector que contengan, como mínimo, las letras del string (ya sea en orden, separadas, repetidas o que hayan otras letras a parte de estas). ¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

Lo más cercano que he podido plantear ha sido esto (y aún así me he dado cuenta que no cumple con ello):

```
 void add(vector<string>& v, string& c, vector<string>& r) {
 int i = 0;
 for (auto it = v.begin(); it < v.end(); it++) {
        string words = *it;
     for (auto et = words.begin(); et < words.end(); et++) {
         for (auto ot = c.begin(); ot < c.end(); ot++) {
             if (*ot == *et) {
                 i++;
             }
         }
     }
     if (i >= c.size() && c.size() < words.size()) {
         r.push_back(words);
         i = 0;
     }
 }
}
```

Ejemplo: el string contiene las letras OLHA. Quiero que al buscar en el vector encuentre, por ejemplo, HOLA o ALOH o, si hubiese esta palabra, HOLEAJO (porque contiene las letras OLHA).

Answer (score -1):

El código se explica solo:

```
for (const string& palabra : lista)
    if (tieneTodasLasLetras(palabra, letras))
        palabrasEncontradas.push_back(palabra);
```

No es necesario complicarlo más. `letras` es un `string` con las letras que deben tener todas las palabras, `lista` es un contenedor con las palabras, y `palabrasEncontradas` es el contenedor donde se guardan las palabras que cumplen la condición.

Te dejo la tarea de imaginarte cómo debe ser la función `tieneTodasLasLetras` que satisfaga tus necesidades. Una posible implementación es la siguiente:

```
bool tieneTodasLasLetras(const string& palabra, const string& letras){
    return all_of(letras.begin(), letras.end(), [](char letra) { return palabra.find(letra) != string::npos; });
}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##bVDbboMwDH3PV3hMakFi/YDS9gv2uLdtmtwQaKQQIyfspeq3M0PoZVKtKImPz7GTo/v@rdV6HF@t126oDewshcgGu4O6Y4JY3z4iv0ZH4kcEXUts40mEaghCB4@dCT1qAyHWlVJHIgfRGm8@qMbwLstExpBr8iFCGrKCHh0eGUv4D7uZW5wVSLCJA3tA536oyVNpczSt9XlRLtSN8fWUfa6@c31CTnAB56t6GbRprBCX4st@Gbjd@p5CBZeiUhelrI/Q4dQe0guSAVdnwNkQEfbSPGPqMCshw454OuWYc4HnHJkyuFRzlyRfHizyjEWVpdq8NcTw3B/YpqHFzJvCNpA/s/dm6GLhXTGFpiHCbndrK9f1l1/Lr8fxDw). Por cierto, ese es un [for de rango](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), similar al `for each` de otros lenguajes.

Comment: Entonces, si tengo que hacer este trabajo en C++20 esto no me vale, verdad? XD

Comment: @Kuko por lo que veo no leíste la respuesta *Te dejo la tarea de imaginarte cómo debe ser la función `tieneTodasLasLetras` que satisfaga tus necesidades*. Tampoco prestaste atención al código del link. ¿Quiere un jugo y unas tostadas señor? Pues haztelas.

Comment: antes que nada, tranquilízate.
1- Si supiera como hacer esa función no preguntaría. Llevo menos de 1 mes programando.
2- No vi ningún link, pero no te preocupes que ahora lo miro a ver si lo entiendo.
3- No quiero un jugo y unas tostadas, pero si quisiera y no supiera como ya sabría a quien no preguntar, así que no se preocupe.

Comment: @Kuko siento haber sonado chocante. Solo quería darte una idea para que puedas avanzar por tu cuenta. Creo que uno aprende más cuando lo hace por si mismo. La manera en que cambiaste tu pregunta me dio a entender que tal vez eres una de esas personas que quieren que hagas sus deberes. De vez en cuando aparecen de esos. Por cierto, los links están aplicados a ciertas palabras.

Comment: y yo también, pero cuando llevas 5h delante de la pantalla, intentando sacar el fallo que has hecho, sin tener entender ni media de programación, que uno está ya desesperado, lo último que quiere es que le digan que lo haga por él mismo como si no lo hubiese intentado. Por cierto, no sé a que cambio te refieres en la pregunta, no la he reformulado. Otra cosa, no suenas chocante, solo arrogante.

Comment: una última cosa que se me ha pasado. No busco que me hagan los deberes, solo que me digan, aunque sea por una vez, como se hace algo, porque si no lo sé, si no sé ni por donde empezar, complicado está que lo saque. Más cuando ni siquiera lo hago por gusto, sino por quitarme una asignatura de encima que ni me va ni me viene. A todo esto, no te preocupes, aquí no creo que vuelva a preguntar, si eso te molesta, porque para que me digan estas cosas paso.

Comment: @Kuko comprendo que ambos nos equivocamos y te pido disculpas. A veces siento que respondo preguntas y los demás no lo aprecian pero se me pasa. Espero haberte ayudado y que no te alejes del sitio solo por mí culpa, hay muchas personas más que responden preguntas aquí.